# The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

Trying to implement user management with the Sonata User bundle :

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html

I'm under Symfony 4 and I already have installed the SonataAdminBundle

But I have an error when I try to update my composer.

```
!!  In ArrayNode.php line 224:
!!
!!    The child node "db_driver" at path "fos_user" must be configured.
```

I have the feeling this is related to Fos User Bundle but I'm not sure at all...

Please tell me which peace of code I can provide to help you with that cause I really don't know at this point.

Following this link : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html

I have been able to implement all the Getting started part and I was trying to implement the advanced option 5 Security to add user management (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in fact the issue was not related to FOSUser at all...the composer update was putting the wrong message (the good one, but only because the cache clear wasn't working).

I fixed it by going to the php.ini and setting the memory limit to 256M instead, so as the cache clear worked so as the composer update worked.